# Python - remove duplicate of dict that contains list of lists

Tags: python, list

suppose `training_data` is a dict that contains a list of lists
such as `{1: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 5]], 2: [[1], [5], [1, 6]], 3: [[7], [5]]}`

I want to merge each value in `training_data` and then flatten it once to a list so that it will become `[[1,2,3,5],[1,5,6],[7,5]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need **unique elements from the list without maintaining the order of elements in initial list**, then you may use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) here with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). You may use these with *list comprehension* to achieve your desired list as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_dict = {1: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 5]], 2: [[1], [5], [1, 6]], 3: [[7], [5]]}

>>> [list(set(chain.from_iterable(v))) for v in my_dict.values()]
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 5, 6], [5, 7]]
```

**Note:** since dictionaries are unordered in Python <3.6, the order of sub-lists in the resultant lists might differ.

For preserving the order of elements in the sublist while merging, take a look at: *[Pythonic way to merge two overlapping lists, preserving order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30055830/2063361)*

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve the same result with a one-line comprehension, chaining and using a set + sort

```
import itertools

d = {1: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 5]], 2: [[1], [5], [1, 6]], 3: [[7], [5]]}

result = [sorted(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(v))) for v in d.values()]

print(result)
```

outputs:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 5, 6], [5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution, but could anyone tell me if there's a simpler way?

```
training_data = list(chain.from_iterable([transaction for _, transaction in training_data.items()]))

new_training_data = []
for transaction in training_data:
    t = set()
    for i in transaction:
        t = t.union(i)
    new_training_data.append(list(t))
```

Comment: You can replace `[transaction for _, transaction in training_data.items()]` with `training_data.values()`.

Comment: You don't need to convert the chain call to a list. The union code can be shortened to `set().union(*transaction)`. Then the whole thing can be turned into one list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` with list comprehension:

```
training_data = {1: [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 5]], 2: [[1], [5], [1, 6]], 3: [[7], [5]]}

resultList = [sorted(set(elem for subList in training_data[key] for elem in subList)) for key in training_data.keys()]
print(resultList)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 5, 6], [5, 7]]
```